# how can i access array element inside an object and print them all in a bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript

[image]

i want access the three underlined field in in the obj and and print them in in bootstarp table . now i am just getting one only .

```
  var len = data.hits.length;

                            console.log(len);  // len is 10


                            for (var i = 0 ; i <= len ; i ++) 

                            {


                        console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.label);
                        console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.image);
                        console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.url);


                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML  = data.hits[i].recipe.label  ;
                        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = 

                        "<img src= "+ data.hits[i].recipe.image +">";


                        document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = data.hits[i].recipe.url;




                            }
```

my current situation.

[image]

Comment: can you explain a bit more, what was you error or what you want to get from this code.

Comment: i want get the three field from every elements of hits array and print them beautifull in a table like

Comment: so your loop is no iterating 10 times?

Comment: Are you getting output here, `console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.label);` ?

Comment: You are replacing the contents in same element in for loop. Instead you need to create a table with different rows in each loop or create divs dynamically.

Comment: yes ! i am getting all name , image link and url in console @Madhavan.V

Comment: You may want to do like this, `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append data to a element. But in your code you have replaced the element on every loop. You can append table row in following ways.

```js
var len = data.hits.length;

console.log(len);  // len is 10

var tableHtml = "";
for (var i = 0 ; i <= len ; i ++) 
  console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.label);
  console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.image);
  console.log(data.hits[i].recipe.url);

  tableHtml += "<tr>";
  tableHtml += "<td>" + data.hits[i].recipe.label +"</td>" ;
  tableHtml += "<td><img src= "+ data.hits[i].recipe.image +"></td>";
  tableHtml+ = "<td>" + data.hits[i].recipe.url + "</td>";
  tableHtml += "<tr>";
}

document.getElementById("table").innerHTML = tableHtml;
```

```html
<table id='table'>
<table>
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipe' of undefined

Comment: I think there might be spelling mistake .

Comment: or one of the value of property recipe might be undefined.

Comment: everything was right but ( var i = 0 ; i <= len- 1; i ++) ..... but thanks ....it works

Comment: oh yes array index starts from 0, you can do ( var i = 1 ; i <len; i ++) as well